# Order of String Attribute in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, attributes

From the parameter below, I guess that the values in **cast** column of movies will have the pair of brackets removed, then replace the whitespace with a blank and replace the apostrophe with a blank. Am I right?
So the original values in the **cast** column are likely to be ['right','Odd'] and after they undergo the operation as previously stated, it becomes this right,Odd?

```
movies['cast']=movies['cast'].str.strip('[]').str.replace(' ','').str.replace("'",'')
```